# Como corrigir esse problema com o DataGridView Check Box cell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Estou tendo um problema com o *DataGridView checkBox* cell:

Clico no *checkBox*, e ele marca o *Checkbox* e atualiza um campo valor.
Clico novamente, e ele faz o oposto.
Tudo funciona normalmente, até que clico rapidamente no *checkBox*. Dai ele se perde e não marca mais certo, tipo, o *checkbox* não esta marcado na tela, mas o valor esta como True.

Procurei em outros fórums, até encontrei respostas, mas nenhuma que corrija esse problema.

Aqui está o código:

```
private void dgvServico_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvServico.CurrentRow.Cells["Check"];
            if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue)
            {
                //chk.Value = CheckState.Unchecked;
                chk.Value = chk.FalseValue;
                valor -= Convert.ToDouble(dgvServico.CurrentRow.Cells["valorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                txtValorTotal.Text = valor.ToString();
                dgvServico.Refresh();

            }
            else
            {
                //chk.Value = CheckState.Checked;
                chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
                valor += Convert.ToDouble(dgvServico.CurrentRow.Cells["valorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                txtValorTotal.Text = valor.ToString();
                dgvServico.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por que ao receber o click você não dá um enabled false na coluna e no fim da um enabled true, não permitindo que ela seja clicada novamente até que o método especificado seja executado?

Comment: Experimente usar lock para impedir que mais de um evento altere o estado ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei corrigindo esse erro de uma forma bem simples. 
Até quando testei, está tudo funcionado corretamente.

Programei os dois eventos (CellContentClick e CellContentDoubleClick) para chamar a mesma função.
Não me recordo porque ignorei essa idéia antes.
Vou continuar com os testes, para ter certeza, mas ficou assim:

```
private void dgvServico_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SelecionarLinha(e);
    }
private void dgvServico_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SelecionarLinha(e);
    }
private void SelecionarLinha(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvServico.CurrentRow.Cells["Check"];
                if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue)
                {
                    chk.Value = chk.FalseValue;
                    valor -= Convert.ToDouble(dgvServico.CurrentRow.Cells["valorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    txtValorTotal.Text = valor.ToString();
                    dgvServico.Refresh();

                }
                else
                {
                    chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
                    valor += Convert.ToDouble(dgvServico.CurrentRow.Cells["valorDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
                    txtValorTotal.Text = valor.ToString();
                    dgvServico.Refresh();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O motivo dele ficar com o valor errado quando se clica muito rápido é porque neste caso o evento DoubleClick é disparado para o segundo clique, e não tem muito o que fazer para impedir isso.

Uma alternativa para se fazer isso é usar os eventos `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` e `CellValueChanged`

Como exemplo, vamos considerar que você tenha duas colunas no DataGrid, a primeira (coluna 0) é do tipo CheckBox e está com databind para um campo do tipo boolean, a segunda (coluna 1) está com o databind para um campo do tipo double

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //se for a coluna 0 nós precimos que o valor seja atualizado imediatamente
    //então vamos forçar o commit deste valor aqui, disparando assim o evento
    //CellValueChanged
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null)
        return;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        //se é a coluna 0 que foi modificada então é só pegar os valores
        var chk = (bool)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        var val = (double)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
        if (chk)
            valor += val;
        else
            valor -= val;
        label1.Text = valor.ToString();
    }
}
```

Desta forma como estamos tratando a mudança de valor no campo e não o clique do mouse não ocorre o problema